# How to construct 3 column grid which becomes 2 column in medium size materialize css?

Tags: css, materialize

I have total 16 items. I want to construct 3 column grid using that. And it has to become 2 column grid in medium size. I'm using materlize css.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
    Some text inside grid
  </div>
... Same 16 times
</div>
```

Above code supposed to work but some columns are missing while in medium device size?

Answer (score 1):

You can add more class to the class to detect the size of the screen and decide how many columns you want.
For example:

```
<div class="col s1 m3 l4 xl5">
        <!-- Promo Content 1 goes here -->
</div>
```

See more at: https://materializecss.com/grid.html

Comment: I have updated question with code... Can you please check it